# style for checkboxes with formidable plugin

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I'm trying to make custom style for checkboxes using CSS/JS

This is currently located at http://www.fb-navigatio.com/markersparebank2/.

I created the style for checkbox:

```
.frm_checkbox label input{
    display:none;   
}
.frm_checkbox label {
    background: url("images/check_sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding: 4px 0 8px 42px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.frm_checkbox label:hover {
    background: url("images/check_sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -40px;
}
.frm_checkbox label.checked{
    background: url("images/check_sprite.png") no-repeat scroll 0 -80px;    
}
```

Here is the JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var tmp = [];
    $('input:checkbox').each(function(index){
        tmp[index] = '';
    })
    $('.frm_checkbox label').click(function(index){

        if(tmp[index] == ''){
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $(this).find('input:checkbox').addAttr('checked');
            console.log(tmp[index]);
        }else if(tmp[index] =='1') {
            tmp[index] = '0';
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).find('input').removeAttr('checked');
            console.log(tmp[index]);
        }
        //var $checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox');
        //$checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
        //alert();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the checkboxes do not work. Clicking on a checkbox does not seem to check it.

Comment: Great, you've done work on this. What is the problem?

Comment: it does not work, please check the link
fb-navigatio.com/markersparebank2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some potential issues I see off the bat:

1. jQuery doesn't have the functions `addAttr` and `removeAttr`. You should be using `prop('checked', true)` and `prop('checked', false)`, as covered in this question:
   [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)
   Documentation for jQuery can be found [on its website](http://jquery.com/).
2. You are setting initial values for `tmp` using indices from checkboxes, but are then trying to use these indices for labels. This is a bit risky. I would recommend attaching data attributes to the elements themselves: `$checkbox.data('checkedState', false)`
3. Your if-else statements check for whether the `tmp` value equals `''` or `'1'`. However, you also have `'0'`, which you set when unchecking. Since you never check for `'0'`, that means you will never be able to check a checkbox after unchecking it. You could just have two values, instead of the third default value of `''`

Let me know if those suggestions solve your problem. If not, please set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that others can try out, debug, and modify the code themselves.